# On Prem SQL Server: Log shipping via Azure Blob Storage: Possible?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, log-shipping

This is about on premise, regular SQL Server 2014, Standard edition.

This is NOT about SQL Azure. The only part of Azure in this conversation is Azure Blog Storage, as a transport for some bits (SQL backups and logs)

Scenario:

Primary SQL Server is in data center 1.

Backup is in data center 2.

In SQL 2014, is it possible to use the "backup to url/azure blob storage" to be the log shipping pipeline?

We like the idea of backup of db and logs to azure blob storage. Great, easy, automatic off site storage of backups.

Would be awesome to use the same pipeline for log shipping to backup db server.

Doable?

(Notes: Neither server is member of a domain. These are two stand alone servers, with no AD or other relationship with each other.)

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn606287.aspx)?

Comment: @PaulWhite No, I had not (and I did google around a bit). That is a big doc. Will review it!

Comment: @PaulWhite fyi, MS seems to have pulled that post... "This topic is no longer available"  I saw it when you first posted it, even read it. (even printed it! But tossed the hard copy.) but now it is gone.

Comment: Available in the internet archive https://web.archive.org/web/20140411053419/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn606287.aspx though the sample files download referenced isn't there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but only manually - Azure Blob Storage isn't integrated into the log shipping wizards. You would need to do your own backups to Azure Blob Storage, and then have the secondary server(s) restore from ABS using the same certificates.

When other shops have done similar projects with AWS's S3 storage (writing their SQL Server backups there using 3rd party tools), I've seen them either log backups to a text file that the other SQL Servers check for backup files, or log entries into a centrally accessible table (like SQL Azure or Amazon RDS) and fetch the backup file names from there.

Comment: Is there an example implementation/script out there I can reference?

Comment: I don't have one I can share, unfortunately.